# Shared memory and POSIX semaphores

Tags: c, concurrency, posix, ipc

I wrote simple consumer-producer program in C. It is working fine while I have 1 producer and 1 consumer. But it is acting strange when I increase number of consumers.

1. I start the producer process
2. Producer is producing
3. I start the consumer process
4. Consumer is consuming and producer is producing
5. I start the consumer process no 2
6. Consumer process no2 never gets an element
7. When I start consumer no3, no4... and so on, the same happens

Second problem:

1. Producer produced maximum of elements
2. Consumer consumes all elements, but producer does not continue to produce anymore

I have no idea why it is happening.

Code:

Producer:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "common.h"

int memoryID;
struct wrapper *memory;
int rc;

void atexit_function() {
    rc = shmctl(memoryID, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    rc = shmdt(memory);
    sem_destroy(&memory->pmutex);
    sem_destroy(&memory->cmutex);
    sem_destroy(&memory->empty);
    sem_destroy(&memory->full);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    atexit(atexit_function);
    //creating key for shared memory
    srand(time(NULL));
    key_t sharedMemoryKey = ftok(".", MEMORY_KEY);
    if (sharedMemoryKey == -1) {
        perror("ftok():");
        exit(1);
    }

    memoryID = shmget(sharedMemoryKey, sizeof(struct wrapper), IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    if (memoryID == -1) {
        perror("shmget():");
        exit(1);
    }

    memory = shmat(memoryID, NULL, 0);
    if (memory == (void *) -1) {
        perror("shmat():");
        exit(1);
    }

    //initialization

    printf("Initializtaion !\n");
    memset(&memory->array, 0, sizeof(memory->array));
    sem_init(&memory->pmutex, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&memory->cmutex, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&memory->empty, 0, SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
    sem_init(&memory->full, 0, 0);
    memory->n = -1;

    if (memoryID == -1) {
        perror("shmget(): ");
        exit(1);
    }


    while(1)
    {
        int r = rand();
        sem_wait(&memory->empty);
        sem_wait(&memory->pmutex);
        memory->n++;
        (memory->array)[memory->n]=r;
        printf("Adding task\t Value:%d\tNumber of tasks waiting:%d \n",r,memory->n);
        usleep(10000);
        sem_post(&memory->pmutex);
        sem_post(&memory->full);
    }

}
```

Consumer:

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "common.h"
#include <sys/shm.h>

int memoryID;
struct wrapper *memory;
int check_prime(int a);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    key_t sharedMemoryKey = ftok(".",MEMORY_KEY);
    if(sharedMemoryKey==-1)
    {
        perror("ftok():");
        exit(1);
    }
    memoryID=shmget(sharedMemoryKey,sizeof(struct wrapper),0);

    if(memoryID==-1)
    {
        perror("shmget(): ");
        exit(1);
    }

    memory = shmat(memoryID,NULL,0);
    if(memory== (void*)-1)
    {
        perror("shmat():");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&memory->full);
        sem_wait(&memory->cmutex);

        int n = memory->n;
        int temp = (memory->array)[n];
        printf("Removed item: %d\tPrime:%d\tNumer of tasks left:%d\n",
            temp, check_prime(temp),n);
        memory->n--;
        usleep(10000);

        sem_post(&memory->cmutex);
        sem_post(&memory->empty);
    }

}
```

common.h:

```
#define MEMORY_KEY 12
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 10
struct wrapper
{
    int array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
    sem_t empty;
    sem_t pmutex;
    sem_t cmutex;
    sem_t full;
    int n;
};
```

Comment: I think you have to leave time to other process to take the sem. Eg. sleep your while 1 after sem release.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help

Comment: the posted code seems unnecessarily complex.  It seems that there is no/zero need for any semaphore.   The data needs a mutex, a counter, and an array.  the consumers need to sleep for a little while when no object/int available to process.  The producer needs to sleep for a little while when the array is full.  I would also suggest, to avoid old data not getting processed in a timely manner, that the array be treated as a circular list, with a head and tail pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I was setting `int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);`
I was setting `pshared` value to 0 but:

> ```
>    The pshared argument indicates whether this semaphore  is  to  be  shared  between  the
>    threads of a process, or between processes.
>
>   If  pshared  has  the  value  0,  then the semaphore is shared between the threads of a
>    process, and should be located at some address that is visible to all threads (e.g.,  a
>    global variable, or a variable allocated dynamically on the heap).
>
>   If  pshared  is  nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes, and should be
>    located in a region of shared memory (see shm_open(3), mmap(2), and shmget(2)).  (Since
>    a  child  created  by fork(2) inherits its parent's memory mappings, it can also access
>    the semaphore.)  Any process that can access the shared memory region  can  operate  on
>    the semaphore using sem_post(3), sem_wait(3), etc.
> ```