How to know how many processes linked with this shared memory?
I am using System V shared memory api in linux.
My model is 1 writer vs N reader.
I want to avoid N writer, write together, so I need to check if there is other process is writing.
How Can I know this?
The code can be found here: linux sys/shm.h latency can be 20us?

I don't know about the linux API. But in boost for example you can place a mutex object in shared memory and use it to synchronize only one writer. Maybe there's something similar in linux API.

You can pass a flag into pthread_mutex_create to make a mutext interprocess. The same goes for conditional variables. You can also put std::atomic into shared memory. In general it's not a Linux specific question, you have to decide on how to synchronize the code.

I want to avoid N writer, write together, .... implement appropriate synchronization mechanism. To begin with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736985/how-synchronization-is-done-in-shared-memory-data-linux-c

One way to control access would be to declare a semaphore (via semget()) and then have each reader or writer lock/decrement that semaphore (via semop()) before accessing the shared memory data, and unlock/inccrement it afterwards.
